# Button on_press function only working one time in Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I have a piece of code that creates buttons displaying objects from a database. It creates the buttons, puts them in a ScrollView object, which is then added to a GridLayout with the id 'grids'. However this process only works once. If I were to change the text I input, and press the search button again to activate the on_press function, nothing changes. It will work if I close and restart the program however.

Python code -->

```
def refresh(self, tags):
    for c in list(self.children):
        if isinstance(c, ScrollView): 
            self.remove_widget(c)
    tags = tags.lower()
    docs = db.collection('objects').where('type', '==', tags).stream()
    layout = GridLayout(cols = 1, spacing = 5, size_hint_y = None)
    layout.bind(minimum_height = layout.setter('height'))
    for doc in docs:
        button = RoundedButton(text = doc.get('specificType'), size_hint_y = None, height = 100)
        layout.add_widget(button)
    root = ScrollView(size_hint = (1, None), size = (Window.width, Window.height))
    root.add_widget(layout)
    self.ids.grids.add_widget(root)
```

Kivy code -->

```
<MainScreen>:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (245/255,245/255,245/255,245/255)
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    GridLayout:
        cols:1
        spacing:5
        size_hint_y:1
        id: grids
        GridLayout:
            id: box
            cols:2
            size_hint_y: None
            height:30
            pos_hint: {'center_x':  0.5, 'center_y':1}
            TextInput: 
                id: ti
                hint_text: 'Search'
                size_hint: 1, 0.05
                text_size: self.width, self.height
                background_normal: ''
            Button:
                text: 'search'
                size_hint_x: 0.1
                on_press: root.refresh(root.ids.ti.text)
```

Comment: You are adding `ScrollView` to `self.ids.grids`, but you are trying to remove it from `self`.

Comment: I tried changing my code to this:
        for c in list(self.children):
            if isinstance(c, ScrollView): 
                self.ids.grids.remove_widget(c)
but I'm still encountering the same issue
@JohnAnderson

Comment: Since the `ScrollView` is a child of `self.ids.grids`, you need to look for it in the `self.ids.grids.children`, not `self.children`.