# How to switch screens in Kivy from Button class

Tags: python, kivy

Usually to switch screens you would have to use a code such as `self.manager.current = "screen_name"`. But this would be done from a screen class.  However I need to switch screens from a custom button class I made, so I was wondering how I would be able to call on ScreenManager from the button class.

This is the code for my button class -->

```
<RoundedButton@Button>
    background_color: (0,0,0,0)
    background_normal: ''
    on_press: app.last_clicked_button = self.text 
    on_release: app.which_clicked()
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (1,0,0,1)
        RoundedRectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
            radius: [10]
```

I have set the button press to reference app for now, but I am unable to switch screens from there. Since this is a button class I am unable to call on manager.
The idea is that the code will automatically gather elements from a database, and then create buttons on the main screen, which will take the features from the class RoundedButton. From there I am trying to add a function, that when executed will switch to another screen. The code below shows how the buttons are formed and take the class.

```
class MainScreen(Screen):
def on_enter(self):
    Clock.schedule_once(self.load_buttons)

def load_buttons(self,*args):
    docs = db.collection('objects').stream()
    layout = GridLayout(cols = 1, spacing = 5, size_hint_y = None)
    layout.bind(minimum_height = layout.setter('height'))
    for doc in docs:
        button = RoundedButton(text = doc.get('specificType'), size_hint_y = None, height = 100)
        layout.add_widget(button)
    root = ScrollView(size_hint = (1, None), size = (Window.width, Window.height))
    root.add_widget(layout)
    self.ids.grids.add_widget(root)

def refresh(self, tags):
    for c in list(self.children):
        if isinstance(c, ScrollView): 
            self.remove_widget(c)
    tags = tags.lower()
    docs = db.collection('objects').where('type', '==', tags).stream()
    layout = GridLayout(cols = 1, spacing = 5, size_hint_y = None)
    layout.bind(minimum_height = layout.setter('height'))
    for doc in docs:
        button = RoundedButton(text = doc.get('specificType'), size_hint_y = None, height = 100)
        layout.add_widget(button)
    root = ScrollView(size_hint = (1, None), size = (Window.width, Window.height))
    root.add_widget(layout)
    self.ids.grids.add_widget(root)
```

Comment: The answer depends on how your `App` is constructed. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: I tried including more information on how the buttons work, and why I'm using a custom button class. The App Class itself however has nothing notable aside from the temporary function which.clicked(self) that I'm keeping there.

Comment: I'm not sure if you were notified of the change so I'll add this @JohnAnderson

Comment: How your `App` class is constructed will determine how your `Screen` is accessed.

Comment: Alright after checking over the app class I think I figured out how to do it. I ended up     def build(self):
        self.screen_manager = RootWidget()
        return self.screen_manager
using this code under app to call on the rootwidget, which was my screenmanager. 
And then under the button code I added this line:
 mainapp.screen_manager.current = 'map_viewer' to call on screen manager